# Android: How to convert string into date

Tags: java, android, caldroid

I am currently working on a calendar application using Caldroid and the date that Caldroid returns looks like this:

```
Fri Jun 17 12:31:00 GMT+07:00 2016
```

I just need to extract the date from it like for example:

```
17-06-2016
```

How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: check out the link >> https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    try {
        //This will give you the desired output
        df2.format(df.parse("Fri Jun 17 12:31:00 GMT+07:00 2016"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SimpleDateFormat. Please refer to the address  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/simpledateformat.html